# Cannot run tests with org.scalatest.tools.Runner from command line

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have my test compiled in a directory: `samplesuite`
It works when running one Suite using `org.scalatest.run`.
Nothing happens when I try to run the directory that contains several suites.

```
scala -cp "..\mytestframework\target\scala-2.12\mytestframework-assembly-0.1.jar;../../Downloads/scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar;..\..\Downloads\scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar" org.scalatest.run samplesuite.SomeSpec
```

But it won't run when trying:

```
    scala -cp "..\mytestframework\target\scala-2.12\mytestframework-assembly-0.1.jar;../../Downloads/scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar;..\..\Downloads\scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar" org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R samplesuite
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming tests are defined in package `samplesuite`, for example

```
package samplesuite
class SomeSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers
```

and current working directory `.` is one level above `samplesuite`, then discover and run all suites with

```
scala -cp "..\mytestframework\target\scala-2.12\mytestframework-assembly-0.1.jar;../../Downloads/scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar;..\..\Downloads\scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar" org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R .
```

In general, when [specifying runpath](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.tools.Runner$@specifyingARunpath) from which tests will be discovered with `-R` point to the *root* directory where your packages start, or to the `.jar` file generated with `sbt test:package`:

```
scala -cp target/scala-2.12/classes:scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar:scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R target/scala-2.12/test-classes

scala -cp target/scala-2.12/classes:scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar:scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R target/scala-2.12/how-can-i-perform-an-or-with-scalatest_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
```

Comment: Thanks Mario. Is it possible to specify `samplesuite` as well? If for some reason, it wouldn't be possible to run it from `.`, how can I do it?

Comment: Yes, it can run from anywhere. Please see edited answer.